# Meteor: count by group aggregate

Tags: meteor

I have created code to **count** data collection by using **group aggregate** but now I have problem where the process count group cannot give the correct result. I don't know where the problem is.

The result from this code is like this [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fxCT.jpg). There is my code:

```
//js

Template.laporankategori.helpers({
  profilcount: function() {
    var subs = {};
    Profil.find().forEach(function(e) {
      if (subs[e.kategori] == null)
        subs[e.kategori] = 0;
      subs[e.kategori] += e.amount;
    });

    var result = [];
    _.each(subs, function(value, key) {
      result.push({kategori: key, amount: value});
    });

    return result;
  }
});



//publish
Meteor.publish("profilcount",function(args) {
    var sub = this;

    var db = MongoInternals.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver().mongo.db;

    var pipeline = [
      { "$group": {
        "_id": "$kategori",
        count:{$sum:amount}
      }}
        ];

   db.collection("profil").aggregate(        
        pipeline,

        Meteor.bindEnvironment(
            function(err, result) {
                _.each(result, function(e) {
                  sub.added("profil", Random.id(), {
                    kategori: kategori._id,
                    amount: kategori.count
                  });
                });
                sub.ready();
            },
            function(error) {
                Meteor._debug( "Error doing aggregation: " + error);
            }
        )
    );
});
```

//html
`{{#each profilcount}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{kategori}}</td>
            <td>{{ amount}}</td>

</tr>
   {{/each}}`

I want the result like this.  [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LghX.jpg)

Comment: What is the result of the aggregate (the object itself)? Didn't you mean `count:{$sum: '$amount'}` in the `$group` stage?

Comment: yes i mean it but nothing result from this code.

Comment: Try to break it down a bit and isolate the issue. Check the results of the aggregate itself and make sure that they match your expectations. Then make sure that the client gets the right data from the collection, then finally make sure that your presentation logic works. Right now there are multiple places where things can go wrong.

Comment: what do you want sum of the amount or count of records??

Comment: I want count categories where their have ** 'PTR' ,'KOM','LCD'** and I want the result like this.   `PTR    2` `KOM 4`.

Answer (score 0):

I have other solution for this, without using aggregate. Just in case if it helps you.

//js

```
Template.laporankategori.helpers({
 profilcount () {
  var result = [];
  var categs = [];
  profil.find().forEach(function(profil) {
   if(categs.indexOf(profil.kategori) > -1) {
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      var res = result[i];
      var count = res.count + 1;
      var amount = res.amount + profil.amount;
      result[i].count = count;
      result[i].amount = amount;
      break;
    }
   } else {
   result.push({
      name: profil.kategori,
      amount : profil.amount,
      count : 1
    });
    categs.push(profil.kategori);
   }
  });
  return result;
 }
});

Meteor.publish("profil",function(args) {
  return profil.find({},{fields: {amount: 1, kategori:1}});
});
```

//HTML

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
          <td> Kategori </td>
          <td> Total Amount</td>
          <td> Count </td>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     {{#each profilcount}}
         <tr>
              <td>{{ name }}</td>
              <td>{{ amount }}</td>
              <td>{{ count }}</td>
          </tr>
    {{/each}}
   </tbody>
</table>
```